# Firebase Auth, in custom tokens what some-uid should be?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

```
const uid = 'some-uid';

getAuth()
  .createCustomToken(uid)
  .then((customToken) => {
    // Send token back to client
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error creating custom token:', error);
  });
```

I don't know what to put in "some-uid" in this scenario. Maybe I should put in a unique id that has never been used. I plan to do other social sign in & up that firebase does not provide.

---

by the way, If implemented like this, will it fit well in the firebase console authentication list, just like a successful Google login? with uid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom tokens are generally used when you have your own authentication system but still want to use Firebase authentication to use feature like auth in security rules.

> I plan to do other social sign in & up that firebase does not provide.

In such cases, ideally you must be storing some UID in your database (where you store users' information) to identify users. You should pass the same UID in `createCustomToken()` so it's used in Firebase auth as well and a Firebase Auth User is associated with your custom auth user.

Comment: Firebase UID is not provided and I have no choice but to receive a unique value from a third party and use it to sign in with a custom token? So it is the only way.. Hm that would be not so clean.. Only that user document should have an additional field value <third-party-uid>, and the <provider> should be also stored it in a separate field value. And the function cannot be called even when FirebaseUser.currentUser.uid? You cannot have the uid provided by Firebase right. (Custom token is basically not a UID right)

Comment: @gaesae like are you string users info in Firestore or so? Maybe you can use the document ID as that'll that'll unique to that user. No the token is not UID

Comment: I just implemented sign in with custom tokens.. and then I realized that the uid comes out as the uid I wrote down. It doesn't create randomly like when using gmail. that is maybe impossible right?

Comment: If you want to randomly generate UIDs you can use something like UUID.

Comment: I want to create a UID exactly provided by Firebase. (no duplicated, distributed) but that seems impossible

Comment: @gaesae why aren't you using Firebase auth's [`createUser()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) method instead of `createCustomToken` that'll auto generate the UID?

Comment: Oh it works without custom tokens??? I didn`t know that. I'll check out this, then when custom token used instead of createUser()?

Comment: @gaesae custom tokens are used when you have any other auth system other than Firebase... if you just want to use Firebase then you can use `createUser` and then log user in on client side using `signInWithEmailAndPassword()`.

Comment: Yes I have a thrid party sign in system. But regardless of that, it still can make accout using createUser instead of custom claims isn't it?(in my case the sign up in DB is the real purpose not only for email certificates stuffs) And createUser and singInWithEmail is whole different story, it has a password system issues. They are not directly connected

Comment: @gaesae as you have your third party auth system, it's recommended to use user's UID in that system in Firebase auth as well so you can easily identify the users.

Comment: Anyway thanks I will refer your opinions appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

As Dharamarj commented, you'll typically either use the ID from the 3rd party system and prefix it with something that identifies the provider, or you generate you own (unique) IDs.

In the latter case, if you are using a 3rd party auth system, you'll want to maintain a mapping from your UIDs to the identifiers of the 3rd party system.

Comment: Firebase UID is not provided and I have no choice but to receive a unique value from a third party and use it to sign in with a custom token? So it is the only way.. Hm that would be not so clean.. Only that user document should have an additional field value <third-party-uid>, and the <provider> should be also stored it in a separate field value. And the function cannot be called even when FirebaseUser.currentUser.uid? You cannot have the uid provided by Firebase right. (Custom token is basically not a UID right)

Comment: I just implemented sign in with custom tokens.. and then I realized that the uid comes out as the uid I wrote down. It doesn't create randomly like when using gmail. that is maybe impossible right?